# how to find first node (head) of circular linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I have question regarding circular linked list,

**1. How to find first node (head) of circular linked list?**

**2.  what is the practical use of circular linked list, why we need it?**

i have gone through lots of forums and website but did not find up to the mark answers.

Thanks all for your time.

Comment: "caracking the coding interview" - that's where the answer is

Comment: Search engines are wonderful things. A search for "uses of circular linked list" reveals this Stack Overflow question, which is also listed as a related question on this current page. You really should learn to do your own research. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589772/why-exactly-do-we-need-a-circular-linked-list-singly-or-doubly-data-structur

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. You normally maintain a head pointer along with the nodes.

Comment: k but what is the practice use with examples?